# class M and Class F are two classes .why "super()" method of F is calling the init method of M? Surely class M is not a parent of class F

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

class M and F are two standalone classes. Class C inherits both F and M . I don't understand why the super() keyword of class F is calling the init of class M . Can someone explain the working behind this code?

```
 class M:
       def __init__(self):
         print("M constructor")


class F:
       def __init__(self):
          print("F constructor")
          super().__init__()
          super().__init__()

class C(F,M):
     def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print("C constructor")

C()
```

The O/P

F constructor

M constructor

M constructor

C constructor

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Python's super() work with multiple inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance)

Comment: `super()` doesn't really mean "the parent of this class"; it means "the next class in the method resolution order", which can be something entirely different in the case of multiple inheritance.

Comment: *"why the super() keyword of class F is calling the init of class M"* Because it is still a `C` instance. Add `print(super().__init__)` (without `()`) and see.